# Fail build gcc 4.8.2 on CentOS 6.5

Tags: gcc, centos6, gcc4.8

Okay so I wanted to run QtCreator on CentOS6.5 and apparently it needs a reasonably up-to-date version of gcc (4.8.2) so here I am trying to do what QT5 creators suggested. when I try to build gcc it stops at this error and I have no idea what's wrong, here's where the gcc compiler dumped out:

```
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating testsuite/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing default commands
make[3]: Entering directory `/root/objdir/build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libiberty'
if [ x"" != x ]; then \
      gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2  -I. -I/root/objdir/../gcc-4.8.2/libiberty/../include  -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wc++-compat -Wstrict-prototypes -pedantic   /root/objdir/../gcc-4.8.2/libiberty/regex.c -o pic/regex.o; \
    else true; fi
gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2  -I. -I/root/objdir/../gcc-4.8.2/libiberty/../include  -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wc++-compat -Wstrict-prototypes -pedantic  /root/objdir/../gcc-4.8.2/libiberty/regex.c -o regex.o
/tmp/ccnwYcKf.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccnwYcKf.s:119: Error: expecting string instruction after `rep'
make[3]: *** [regex.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/objdir/build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libiberty'
make[2]: *** [all-build-libiberty] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/objdir'
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/objdir'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Please help thank you :)

Edit: Okay I figured out how to get things rolling:

1. you need to install devtoolset 2.1
2. then install devtoolset-libutils
3. follow gnu build instuctions, should build fine now.

The error was because of outdated libutils that come with centos.